# How do I force Windows Update to get Updates from Microsoft via a bat or vbs file

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-updates

I'm a Tier 1 remote tech for a large company. Our Windows PC s are managed and updates are pushed to users. These updates are verified secured via a 3rd party before they are sent to users. This often means that users only get major updates and dependencies are often missed, which causes problems. All users have an option to "check for updates from Microsoft" in the Windows update GUI and doing so resolves most of these kinds of issues. I often have to tell users to run Windows updates several times over a few days and I'd like to make that easier for them

I'd like a batch or vbs script that does it automatically.

To be clear the script has to execute the command to check for updates from microsoft, not our WSUS servers.

Can this be done?

Comment: I would google Windows update Bach files or even windows updates VBS.   Google is your friend!

Comment: @Sorceri Ive tried that. They all trigger the normal "Check for updates" command that gets updates from our WSUS servers. I need one that gets them from Microsoft.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/searching--downloading--and-installing-updates